# Retrieve id_token based on access_token in API

Tags: asp.net-core, openid-connect, identityserver4

We are current building a collection of back-end ASP.NET Core microservices. These services will not be accessed directly from the front-end application, but rather accessed through an ASP.NET Core API gateway. We are using IdentityServer4 for the OpenID Connect server. I have been able to setup the `UseJwtBearerAuthentication` middleware to have API gateway validate the JWT bearer token (access_token) against IdentityServer4. I would like to be able to have the API gateway inject the id_token, based on the access_token, into the requests made to the back-end services that may need to know the end-user.

Is there a way to configure the JWT middleware to retrieve the id_token when validation the access_token or do I need to manually call the OpenID Connect server in the API gateway?

Comment: Why don't you use access_token instead of id_token on the backend service(just i am wondering).

Answer (score 2):

You don't use id_tokens at APIs - they are for clients.

If you want to have access to certain identity claims, either include them in the access token (by configuring the ScopeClaims on the resource scope), or use the access token to contact the userinfo endoint which in turn will return the identity claims.

Answer (score 0):

The JWT middleware performs standalone verification, it does not contact the identity server to verify or retrieve anything. You'll have to make an additional call.

Comment: I don't know if that's completely true. One, the JWT middleware config take sthe URL to the authority (OpenID Connect server in my case). Also, when I hit my API with the access_token, I do see the OpenID Connect server being hit in the logs. So, I do think the JWT validates the access_token on each request to see if it's still valid. It still may be true that I need to make an additional call to retrieve the id_token.

Comment: So it looks like it's hitting the OpenID Connect server to get the config in order to retrieve the signing key.

Comment: Ah, yes, but that's a one time download at startup, it is not per request/token. It can also be configured locally so the startup download isn't needed.